# fromPromise observable emits values without subscribing to it

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm not sure why this still triggers an HTTP request even though I haven't subscribed to the saveCourse$ observable.

Does fromPromise function handle subscriptions differently?

```
this.form.valueChanges
  .pipe(filter(() => this.form.valid))
  .subscribe(changes => {
    const saveCourse$ = fromPromise(
      fetch(`/api/courses/${this.course.id}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify(changes),
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json'
        }
      })
    );
  });
```

Comment: `fetch` immediately starts the request.

Comment: You likely want to use the `HttpClient` to do your Http calls.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I know. This is just for learning purposes. I'm exploring RxJS library and I thought `fromPromise` would magically transform a `Promise` to an `Observable` that I can subscribe to later. Otherwise what's `fromPromise` good for?

Comment: Think of `fromPromise` as a _wrapper_ around the `Promise`. It will allow you to pipe it, and use it in pipes. It doesn't change how the inner promise works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fetch` will fire the http call on the invocation (remember promises are not lazy).

If you want the function to be called only on subscribe use `defer()` :

```
defer(() => fetch(myUrl)).pipe(...)
```

If you want a lazy fetch, rxjs already come from [`fromFetch`](https://rxjs.dev/api/fetch/fromFetch) :

```
import { fromFetch } from 'rxjs/fetch';

fromFetch(myUrl).pipe(...)
```

Comment: You might want to link to the documentation of `fromFetch`, as you omitted the parameters OP passes to `fetch`.

Comment: @Cerbrus Good addition, I also provided the defer wrapper.